# Unable to link with libx264.lib static library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, linker, libx264

I'm building custom video encoder using x264 as a static library. I've followed [this](http://kemuri9.net/dev/x264/other/intel_howto.html) guide in order to build static library. Trying to compile this:

```
x264_t * setup_encoder(int width, int height){
    x264_param_t param;
    x264_param_default_preset(&param, "veryfast", "zerolatency");
    param.i_threads = 1;
    param.i_width = width;
    param.i_height = height;
    param.i_fps_num = 26;
    param.i_fps_den = 1;
    // Intra refres:
    param.i_keyint_max = 26;
    param.b_intra_refresh = 1;
    //Rate control:
    param.rc.i_rc_method = X264_RC_CRF;
    param.rc.f_rf_constant = 25;
    param.rc.f_rf_constant = 25;
    param.rc.f_rf_constant_max = 35;
    //For streaming:
    param.b_repeat_headers = 1;
    param.b_annexb = 1;
    x264_param_apply_profile(&param, "baseline");

    return x264_encoder_open(&param);
}
```

Results in:

> main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl x264_param_default_preset(struct x264_param_t *,char const *,char const *)"
>
> main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl x264_param_apply_profile(struct x264_param_t *,char const *)"
>
> main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "struct x264_t * __cdecl x264_encoder_open_136(struct x264_param_t *)"
>
> %PROJECT_DIR%: fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals

Linker scans libx264.lib, but can't find anything inside.

```
Searching .\lib\libx264.lib:
```

With dumpbin /HEADERS I can actually find the declaration I need, but linker is unable to do it.

```
SECTION HEADER #38
   .text name
       0 physical address
       0 virtual address
     E60 size of raw data
    930C file pointer to raw data (0000930C to 0000A16B)
    D219 file pointer to relocation table
       0 file pointer to line numbers
      40 number of relocations
       0 number of line numbers
60501020 flags
         Code
         COMDAT; sym= x264_param_default_preset
         16 byte align
         Execute Read
```

Enviroment is Visual Studio 2012 with Intel Compiler 14 on Windows 8 64-bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try including using C style bindings.

```
extern "C" {
#include <x264.h>
}
```

Comment: Getting multiple definitions of multiple functions (in libcmt.lib), so unable to link anyway. How does your code exactly works?